# Nested Namespace Update Action No route matches [PATCH]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, nested-routes

Been trying to progress through rails using namspacing, there's been similar questions I think my problem is everything is namespaced.

I tried adding a class to the models (did that before with devise user with nest object and worked) but it doesn't seem to work when dealing with namespaces.

I get a routing error.

```
 No route matches [PATCH] "/backend/membercontacts/1/memberlistings"
```

routes.rb

```
# Application Client Backend
namespace :backend do
    # Member Routes
    resources :membercontacts do
        resources :memberaddresses
        resources :memberlistings
    end
end
```

backend/memberlisting.rb

```
class Backend::Memberlisting < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Model Relationships
    belongs_to :membercontact

end
```

backend/membercontact.rb

```
class Backend::Membercontact < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Model Relationship
    has_many :memberlistings, dependent: :destroy

end
```

backend/memberlistings_controller.rb

```
class Backend::MemberlistingsController < ApplicationController

    # Security & Action Filters
    layout '/backend/application.html.erb'
    before_action :set_memberlisting, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    # Member Listing Index
    def index
        membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
        @memberlistings = membercontact.memberlistings.order('mlcontactname ASC')
    end

    # Detailed Member Listing Profile
    def show
        membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
        @membercontact = membercontact.memberlistings.find(params[:id])
    end

    # New Member Listing
    def new
        membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
        @memberlisting = membercontact.memberlistings.build
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # new.html.erb
            format.xml  { render :xml => @membercontact }
        end
    end

    # Edit Member Listing
    def edit
        membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
        @memberlisting = membercontact.memberlistings.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Create Member Listing Action
    def create
        @membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
        @memberlisting = @membercontact.memberlistings.create(memberlisting_params)
        respond_to do |format|
        if @memberlisting.save
            format.html { redirect_to backend_membercontact_memberlistings_path, notice: 'Address for Membercontact was Successfully Created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @memberlisting }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'new' }
                format.json { render json: @memberlisting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # Update Member Listing Action
    def update
        respond_to do |format|
        if @memberlisting.update(memberlisting_params)
            format.html { redirect_to backend_membercontact_memberlistings_path, notice: 'Address for Membercontact was Successfully Updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'edit' }
                format.json { render json: @memberlisting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # Delete Member Listing Action
    def destroy
        @membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
        @memberlisting = @membercontact.memberlistings.find(params[:id])
        @memberlisting.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to backend_membercontact_memberlistings_path, notice: 'Address for Membercontact was Successfully Deleted.'  }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        end
    end

    private

    def set_memberlisting
        @memberlisting = Backend::Memberlisting.find(params[:id])
    end

    def memberlisting_params
        params.require(:backend_memberlisting).permit(:mlcontactname, :mlcompanyname, :mladdressline1, :mladdressline2, :mlcity, :mlprovince, :mlpostalcode, :mlphone, :mlwebsite, :mlemail, :membercontact_id, :account_id)
    end

end
```

Routes Rake

```
backend_membercontact_memberlistings_path       GET /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings(.:format)  backend/memberlistings#index
                                                POST    /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings(.:format)  backend/memberlistings#create
new_backend_membercontact_memberlisting_path    GET /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/new(.:format)  backend/memberlistings#new
edit_backend_membercontact_memberlisting_path   GET /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id/edit(.:format) backend/memberlistings#edit
backend_membercontact_memberlisting_path        GET /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)  backend/memberlistings#show
                                                PATCH   /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)  backend/memberlistings#update
                                                PUT /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)  backend/memberlistings#update
                                                DELETE  /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)  backend/memberlistings#destroy
```

So far I've tried to work with classes (still learning) in the models file and have tried some variations like below. Also the reason why I define the url path, it defaulted to backend_membercontact_backend_memberlisting

```
, class_name: 'Backend::Memberlisting'
<%= form_for([@memberlisting.membercontact, @memberlisting], url: backend_membercontact_memberlistings_path, method: :post) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Try changing it to `<%= form_for([@memberlisting.membercontact, @memberlisting], url: backend_membercontact_memberlisting_path, method: :patch) do |f| %>`.

Comment: Sure give me a moment

Comment: Thanks that worked. If you can copy that over to an answer I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No route matches [PATCH] "/backend/membercontacts/1/memberlistings"

From your `rake routes` output, the path is `backend_membercontact_memberlisting_path`( no **s** `memberlisting`) not `backend_membercontact_memberlistings_path`

Also, you should change `method: post` to `method: :patch`

```
<%= form_for([@memberlisting.membercontact, @memberlisting], url: backend_membercontact_memberlisting_path, method: :patch) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
<%= form_for([@memberlisting.membercontact, @memberlisting], url: backend_membercontact_memberlisting_path, method: :post) do |f| %>
```

Your are using     `backend_membercontact_memberlistings_path` according to your routes is should be     `backend_membercontact_memberlisting_path`

Hope this works.

Comment: Pavan above already gave a solution. I do believe I tried post and it was creating a new record. I'll try it again to see if that's the case and report back. But thanks for your answer as well.

Comment: This one didn't work unfortunately. It says missing post path.